# Misogyny – books

Tags: social-psychology

I'm looking for some book recommendations that can introduce me to psychological analyses of the problem. Anything related to the topic would also be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[**Men Who Hate Women and the Women Who Love Them**](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/9787.Men_Who_Hate_Women_and_the_Women_Who_Love_Them)

> When Loving Hurts and You Don't Know Why.

[image]

**Susan Forward** and **Joan Torres**